# Output ul tags conditionally in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

Setup: Headless Wordpress CMS, GatsbyJs, GraphQL

I think this is a JavaScript ES6 problem rather than a GatsbyJS problem.

I've got a query that outputs an author, title and url.
The data is queried from an ACF repeater field, so there could be one, none or many items.

Here's the code:

```
  {citationPath &&
    citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        <li key={item.url}>
          <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {item.title}
          </a>
          <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
        </li>
      )
    })}
```

THIS WORKS, no problem.

I now want to put a `<ul>` tag before the code, and a `</ul>` tag after the code ONLY if some `citationPath` items
are returned.

OPTION #1

I could do this:

```
  {citationPath &&
    citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        <ul>
            <li key={item.url}>
            <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                {item.title}
            </a>
            <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        )
    })}
```

but then  I get a `<ul></ul>` around each list item.

OPTION #2

I could do this:

```
<ul>
  {citationPath &&
    citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        
            <li key={item.url}>
            <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                {item.title}
            </a>
            <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
            </li>
        
        )
    })}
</ul>
```

but then I get `<ul></ul>` when NO `citationPath` items are returned.

OPTION #3

When I try this:

```
  {citationPath && parse("<ul>")}
  {citationPath &&
    citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        <li key={item.url}>
          <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {item.title}
          </a>
          <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
        </li>
      )
    })}
  {citationPath && parse("</ul>")}
```

No HTML is printed out on those posts which do not return `citationPath` data. However, on those that do I get the following HTML output:

```
<ul></ul>
<li>
    <a href=[my url] target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
<li>
[more list items ...]
```

So it seems that `{citationPath && parse("<ul>")}` and `{citationPath && parse("</ul>")}` are being executed before:

```
  {citationPath &&
    citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        <li key={item.url}>
          <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {item.title}
          </a>
          <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
        </li>
      )
    })}
```

Note: the reason I don't simply go for OPTION #2 is that I don't want screen readers bumping into empty `<ul></ul>` tags.

Does any one have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the condition above and make sure to check the condition of length.

```js
{citationPath && citationPath.length > 0 && (
  <ul>
    {citationPath.map(item => {
      return (
        <li key={item.url}>
          <a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {item.title}
          </a>
          <p>Author: {item.author}</p>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
)}
```

Since this checks both the `length` and the `true`thy value of `citationPath`, this is the solution you're looking for and as an industry professional, I use this code in production.